# Hibernate: Repeated column in mapping for entity | two embedded classes of the same type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Hibernate throws an exception when creating the tables, because embedded attributes are mapped to the same column.

The class Distance is embedded twice in a class route as followed:

```
@Embeddable
public class Distance implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8466495790824502626L;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected Integer distInSec;

    public Distance() {
        super();
    }
}


@Entity
public class Route{
    @Column(nullable=false)
    protected Distance currentDetour;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    protected Distance currentDist;       
}
```

When hibernate creates the table, it tries to map distInSec of currentDetour as well as of currentDist to the same column "distInSec" in the table route. Hence, the error org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: is thrown.

If possible I would like to change the configuration in the way that it always produces colums with the names currentDetour_distInSec and currentDist_distInSec. Does anybody have an idea how to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy as the naming strategy solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

Use [`@AttributeOverride`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) to customize column names.

Comment: this works, but is not an default configuration. Thank you anyway!